# Size of Shiny Navbar title row changes when resizing window

Tags: css, r, shiny, navbar

How can I get rid of the space below the Navbar title that appears when the window is resized to a smaller size? In the screenshots below, the height of the grey title row seems to be twice as large. Code for a minimal example is below. The change seems to happen at a width of 600px.

[image: App in large window]

[image: App in small window]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Title", id = "navbar", 
  tabsetPanel(id="tabs", 
              tabPanel(value = "tab1", title = "Tab1"),
              tabPanel(value = "tab2", title = "Tab2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `position: absolute;` for your navbar and it will not change below 600px.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                              #navbar {
                                position: absolute;
                              }
                              "))),
    title = "Title", id = "navbar", 
    tabsetPanel(id="tabs", 
                tabPanel(value = "tab1", title = "Tab1"),
                tabPanel(value = "tab2", title = "Tab2")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```